# Unity Textures Not Saving, Textures not Displaying Properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, voxel

In Unity3D I have this problem where I've a Voxel object and I made a material which uses a map of a 16x16 texture. I drag the material onto the voxel, and it works fine. But then, I exit play mode and re-enter, and it's gone! I don't know why, but every time I drag the material on in play mode then exit and re-enter, the texture disappears and is replaced with the ugly magenta No Texture texture. Is there any way I can stop this from happening? Also, The texture, when I drag it on, instead of being a Green background with Dark Green Dots, it just appears fully as a weird Green shade. Any ideas on either of these problems?

Comment: Nothing is saved while in Play mode. You must add the texture while not in play mode.

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't save changes you make to the scene in play mode. Apply the material outside of play mode if you want it to be saved.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I'll try that to solve the not saving problem. Maybe it'll solve the blob problem? I'll add another comment if it doesn't solve the blob problem. Thanks!

Edit: It works on the saving problem! However, the texture still just comes up as a plain blob/shade of green. Any ideas? Thanks!
- Swift :)

Comment: The blob issue sounds like you have messed up UV in the object mesh.

Comment: I fixed the mesh UVs and it works! Thanks so much for your answer, I'm new to unity so it means a lot that you could help me. Thanks! :D